# Can't get Empty WebAPI project to read web.config setting

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I created an Empty WebAPI project with VS 2013. I added the following to my web.config:

In my Controller class, I am trying to read this setting and I get a null exception.

```
    public bool GetConnString(string baseCode, string scope)
    {

        try
        {

            string connstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["isrOAK1"].ToString();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message.ToString();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I tried again to create a new Empty WebAPI project and the same null exception is thrown. I think that the Empty WebAPi is missing something.  How can I fix this to read the conn string setting?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where is your code for web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig1 = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
if (rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
{
    System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement customSetting = rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings["isrOAK1"];
}
```

The setting will need to be in the app setting node in the Web.config